# Word for update/create

Tags: word-choice, programming

Is there an english word, which can be used for both *update* and *create*?

I'm programming a function which creates something if it doesn't exist already, otherwise it updates the stuff. 
A word which came me in mind is *process*. 
Does anyone know a better matching word for this purpose?

Comment: In the SQL family of languages, this is known as an `upsert` (a portmanteau of `update` and `insert`, the latter being the RDBMS analog to "create"). In the Unix family of OSes, the analog is the command `touch` which either creates the named file (so obviously its timestamp is *now*), or causing an existing file of that name to have a timestamp of *now*. In general, you can name functions for what they output, because the client/caller doesn't have to care *how* you produced that result (i.e. whether you took an existing thing and modified it, or created a new one ex nihilio).

Comment: I suggest an alternative to the previously asked question.  If you are looking for an English word (and not a programmatic word), my suggestion is "establish".  It has a denotation of creation and a confirmation of understanding.